# Java 8 Optional and flatMap - what is wrong?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, option-type, flatmap

Some piece of code:

```
public class Player {
    Team team;
    String name;
}

public class Team {
    List<Player> players;
}

public class Demo {

    @Inject
    TeamDAO teamDAO;

    @Inject
    PlayerDAO playerDAO;

    List<String> findTeamMatesNames(String playerName) {
        Optional<Player> player = Optional.ofNullable(playerDAO.get(playerName));

        return player.flatMap(p -> teamDAO.findPlayers(p.team))
            .map(p -> p.name)
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

Why am I not able to do this? In flatMap method I am getting error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to Optional"

My goal is:

1. If optional is present I want to get list of items based on this optional object property
2. If optional is not present I want to return empty list

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What error do you get? And what does teamDAO.finPlayers?

Comment: Where does `team` in `findTeamMatesNames` come from?

Comment: It's not the point what are you asking for.

In flatMap I'am getting: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Player> to Optional<Object>"

Comment: @coolcfan His code is broken, team should be player.

Comment: Looks as if you are mixing stream and optional apis. flatMap() in Optional is for unpacking nested optionals but your lambda is returning a list of Players, not an Optional<Player>.

Comment: @coolcfan sorry, I've made a mistake, now should be ok

Comment: @DirkLachowski how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `map` to perform the desired operation. The `map` operation will not take place if the `Optional` is empty but leave again an empty `Optional`. You can provide the fallback value afterwards:

```
player.map(p -> teamDAO.findPlayers(p.team)).orElse(Collections.emptyList())
```

The mapping from a `List` of `Player` to a `List` of Player’s name `String`s can’t be performed by an `Optional`; that’s a `Stream` task:

```
Optional<Player> player = Optional.ofNullable(playerDAO.get(playerName));
return player.map(p -> teamDAO.findPlayers(p.team)
                           .stream().map(tp -> tp.name).collect(Collectors.toList()))
             .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Comment: I didn't that I have to perform next operations inside first map function. Thanks!

Comment: @dmydlarz: it is also possible to do it afterwards, e.g. `player.map(p -> teamDAO.findPlayers(p.team)).orElse(Collections.emptyList())
.stream().map(tp -> tp.name).collect(Collectors.toList())` has the same semantics but it would imply an unnecessary collect operation performed on the empty stream in case of an empty `Optional`.